# Windows azure cache error - "Cache referred to does not exist. Contact administrator or use the Cache administration tool to create a Cache."

Tags: windows, caching, azure

I have one application on Windows Azure cloud and I'm using Windows Azure Co-Located Cache.

Some times, when I publish the website/webservice, this error appears when I call the `DataCacheFactory.GetCache` method:

> Cache referred to does not exist. Contact administrator or use the Cache administration tool to create a Cache.

This problem can go away after few moments, but some times it never fix, then I need to publish projects again.

The stacktrace is:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ErrStatus errStatus, Guid trackingId, Exception responseException, Byte[][] payload,
 EndpointID destination)     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.EstablishConnection(IEnumerable`1 servers, RequestBody request, Func`3 
sendMessageDelegate, DataCacheReadyRetryPolicy retryPolicy)     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 servers)     
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName, CreateNewCacheDelegate cacheCreationDelegate, 
DataCacheInitializationViaCopyDelegate initializeDelegate)
```

Answer (score 1):

See this link whether it can help you...

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/#comment-743576866

> we were missing the required blob storage container on local
>   devstorage. After creating the following container :
>   'cacheclusterconfigs' everything seems to be working now

'cacheclusterconfigs' container will be created by the service internally.you may accidentally deleted that.

Note: IMO please verify the cache name. By default you will be using the cache named 'default'.

Comment: I have not deleted that as you can see in the following print:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=rti8u0&s=5                       
I have something like 3 diferente cache configs and i dont use the default one.

I realy dont know what is the problem.

Comment: can you post the <dataCacheClients> part of your web.config file

Comment: I've post it as an another answer because the message have been exceeded the maximum length coment allows. Thanks for the attention.